# Single domain, two webservers running on different ports, two different SSL issuers possible?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, iis, domain, certificate

Short, Can a domain have multiple SSL issuers installed on different servers ?

Long ,
I have a domain.
example.com

Its running on two different servers , two different websites, two different ports , same public ip.

Server 1  : example.com : Windows 2016 (expires 4 months from now )
Server 2  : example.com:123 Linux (expires 4 months from now )

I have a Digicert issued and installed for example.com in both servers.

Is it possible to issue a certificate from another SSL issuer (Rapid SSL) for example.com and install it only in Server 2 where as Server 1 still uses Digicert ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple certificates for the same domain active at the same time on different IP addresses for this domain and/or different ports. One can even have multiple certificates on the same IP and port which differ in the public key algorithm (i.e. ECC vs. RSA)

It does not matter if these CA are issued by the same CA or different CA, as long as they are valid and properly served (i.e. with all required intermediate CA).

Comment: Thank you for the information, we will issue a second certificate from a cheaper alternative and if it works fine, we will even switch the primary server. Thanks.